# Increase height of onboard in lock screen

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen, onboard

On my tablet I use a fresh install of trusty with gnome flashback compiz session.
At login screen gnome provides an own on-screen keyboard which is kind of ok.

Within the session I use onboard in normal mode and I enabled it for the unlock screen as well. There it is a little bit too small and I found no way to increase its height.

Adjusting the docked height of onboard does not affect the appearance within the lock screen (where it is docked automatically with no option to change this).

Is there a possibility to increase the dock styled height of onboard at gnome lock screen?

If not, is it possible to display onboard normally (not docked) at gnome lock screen?

If none of them, I am open for proposals of onboard alternatives.

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you still need help, but I have something for you.

Run the following:

```
gsettings set org.onboard.window.landscape dock-height 405
```

It works fine while logged in, so presumably making a script that does this automatically upon lock will work for you.